# Problem with LINQ using the values of a table before a GROUP BY

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, aggregate

I have the following GROUP BY:

```
   var stocks =
       from p in products
       from w in p.Warehouses
       from l in w.locations
       group l by l.Date into g
       let maxDate = g.Max(l1 => l1.Date)
       select new { Product=p.Name, Location= g.Where(l2 => l2.Date == maxDate) };
```

But it isn't working, i think because I am doing a group by I am not allowed to use values from the tables before the group by in my select.

Here is the hierarchy of the objects.

```
 Products

   Each product has multiple warehouses

      Each warehouse has multiple locations.
```

I need to return all products and each product must contain the location name.

What is the criteria to find the location when there are multiple warehouses and multiple locations.

I must search in each warehouse and in turn each location... and return OUT OF ALL OF THEM the latest location (ONLY 1) which I detect using the `Date == maxDate`.

But it won't let me select the "Name" that was in p. It's not in g as g is group by of "locations".

Comment: You're grouping *by date* but then finding the latest date *within each group*. That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Hi Jon, thansk fro the reply. SO what do i need to do... I will try and explain what i have.. I have MANY products, and EACH product has MANY Warehouses and each WareHouse has MANY locations.  The location has a Date. So i need to return the name of the product but only 1 location which is the Latest using the property DATE which is in Location... DOes this make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think so... shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
var query = from product in products
            let location = (from warehouse in p.Warehouses
                            from location in p.Locations
                            orderby location.Date descending
                            select location).FirstOrDefault()
            select new { Product = product.Name,
                         Location = location };
```

Note that `Location` may be null, if there are no matching locations.

There's no *need* to use a `let` clause here, but I figured this would be the most readable way of writing the query.

Now you don't *really* need to sort all the locations, of course... but there's no `MaxBy` in LINQ, which is what you really want. If you're using LINQ to Objects you *could* write your own `MaxBy` method (and there's one in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com)); in LINQ to SQL etc I'd expect the database to optimize the query anyway.

Comment: wow jon, i think thats exactly what i needed! i forgot one property though - warehouse "NAME" so i did this.. it appears to work?    select new {Product = p.Name, Location = location, WarehouseName = warehouse.Name}).FirstOrDefault()   - it seems logical and appears to work :-)

Comment: @Martin: Glad to hear it's working for you :) Don't forget that you don't need the product name in the "inner" part, as you'll still have access to it in the "outer" part.